# Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionComponent<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing modal logic with React and Typescript.
Modals can be centrally managed through the useModals Hook, and components passed as arguments can be opened through the openModal function.
However, an error occurs because the type of component to be passed as an argument to openModal is specified incorrectly.

How can I specify the type well??

error

> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionComponent'.
> Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' provides no
> match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any):
> ReactElement<any, any> | null'.

```js
//useModals
const modalsAtom = atom<
  Array<{
    Component: FunctionComponent<any>;
    props: ComponentProps<FunctionComponent<any>>;
  }>
>({
  key: "modalsAtom",
  default: [],
});

const useModals = () => {
  const [modals, setModals] = useRecoilState(modalsAtom);

  const openModal = useCallback(
    <T extends FunctionComponent<any>>(
      Component: T,
      props: Omit<ComponentProps<T>, "open">
    ) => {
      setModals((modals) => [
        ...modals,
        { Component, props: { ...props, open: true } },
      ]);
    },
    [setModals]
  );
...
}
```

```js
const ConFirmModal = (text:Props) => {....} // return to EmotionJSX.Element

const App = () => {
  const {openModal} = useModals();
   ...

  const onOpenModal = () => {
    openModal(<ConFirmModal text="OK"/>, Props)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @vr.  updated!! please check my code..